# Inserting padding between a link and icon in font awessome

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have a link with a icon of fontawessome:

```
<a class="fa fa-some-icon" href="#">Link1</a>
```

I want to insert padding between the icon and the text. I've tried this:

```
 font-size: 20px; padding: 10px 0;
```

but have had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Add margin-right into `:before` pseudo of the `a` element.

```css
a::before {
    content: "";
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-user">Link1</a>
```

or you can add `width` in `:before` like this:

```css
a::before {
  content: "";
  display:inline-block;
  width:20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-user">Link1</a>
```

Comment: Then edit your HTML-code. You will need another element to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Add some right indents (`margin-right` or `padding-right`) to the styles of `:before` pseudo element where you will add font-awesome class. For example

```
.fa:before {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```css
.custom-link:before {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a class="fa fa-bank custom-link" href="#">Link1</a>
```

Comment: works. how can I also add "  text-decoration: none;"? I've just added it but the icon still becomes underlined. Or should I add an "hover" style?

Comment: @Kumakaja yes, you will need to override hover styles... like `.fa:hover:before { text-decoration: none; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can give some css class to your  and use the ::before selector as below

HTML

```
<a class="some_class fa fa-amazon" href="#">Link1</a>
```

CSS

```
.some_class::before {
  padding-right:15px;
 }
```

Fiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qjmufkk6/)

Answer (score 0):

With padding of before or after psudo selector that can be manage. HTML

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-address-book">Address Book</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-address-card">Address Card</a>
<style>
      a::before {
      content: "";
      padding-right: 10px;
 }
```

Fiddly: http://fiddly.org/9b610

Answer (score 0):

::before insert the content just before element without margin or padding.

You must to do this:

```
<a href="#"><span class="fa fa-some-icon" style="padding-right:10px;"></span>Link1</a>
```